# Refactoring approach to clean up many if elses with the help of java lambdas

Tags: java, code-cleanup

Currently I am cleaning up hard to maintain and test if else clutter which is based on conditions which have to be checked in isolations:

### What is the basic semantic of the conditions?

> Big Entity Objects have to be checked based on two entity keys namely Trans and Right for state change as in the example Below:

```
if (oldTrans.getfOrder().equals(newTrans.getfOrder()) {
     compound.setIsStateChanged(true);
      return;
}
if (oldRight.getfRight().equals(newRight.getfRight()) {
     compound.setIsStateChanged(true);
}
```

Currently the if else are all cluttered up at one place:

```
    if (oldTrans.getfOrder().equals(newTrans.getfOrder()) {
        compound.setIsStateChanged(true);
        LOGGER.info("major change detected");
        return compound;
    } if (oldTrans.getgOrder().equals(newTrans.getgOrder()) {
        compound.setIsStateChanged(true);
LOGGER.info("major change detected");
        return compound;   
    }
```

I see 2 main issues here

1. Every if has a return statement and with so many ifs it hard to know when and a what point method exits.
2. To many if branchings are error prone and The number of conditions is likely to go up.

To avoid so many ifs that are basically based on the same semantic underneath from clean code perspective I tried to solve it the polymorphic way

Extracting the Conditions in Enums as Constants and impleneting a checker Interface that takes new and old objects as params

```
    public interface ICheckStateChange<T>(T old, T new) {
        boolean check(T old, T new);
    }

    //implementations
    public TransChecker implements ICheckStateChange<Trans> {

      List<BiPredicate<Trans, Trans>> allTransConditions = transConditions.getValues();

    public boolean check(Trans oldTrans, Trans newTrans) {
         //all conditions null check here
        //loop through conditions
        for (BiPredicate<Trans, Trans> transCondition: allTransConditions) {
            if (transCondition).test()) {
                return true;
             LOGGER.info("major state change detected, taking apt action")
          }
    }

public RightChecker implements ICheckStateChange<Right> {

      List<BiPredicate<Right, Right>> allTransConditions = RightConditions.getValues();

    public boolean check(Right oldRight, Right newRIght) {
         //all conditions null check here
        //loop through conditions
        for (BiPredicate<Right, Right> rightCondition: allRightConditions) {
            if (rightCondition).test()) {
                return true;
             LOGGER.info("major state change detected, taking apt action")
          }
    }
```

The Conditons are now centrally located as BiPredicate constants using lambdas

```
public enum rightConditions {
    FORDER_CHANGE_NULL_TO_NOT_NULL((Order old, Order new)
       -> old == null && new != null),

    //to be replaced by the right condition
    GORDER_CHANGE_FROM_OPEN_TO_DONE((Order old, Order new)
       -> old == null && new != null)

    //to be replaced by the right condition
    LORDER_CHANGE_FROM_OPEN_TO_REVERTED((Order old, Order new)
       -> old == null && new != null)

........
   }
```

**My question here is about the approach of refactoring the If elses with the help of lambda BiPredicates in hinddight of clean code? Readability, extensibility and maintainability** ;)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I can't understand what your question is. If your question is "will this code compile?", then use your compiler to compile your code, and you'll have your answer.

Comment: What's the question? If the code didn't compile, attach the relevant error logs, else describe if you're observing any unexpected output.

Comment: Question is about if the code is cleaner after refactoring or not, Updated the question statement for clearer understanding.